# LRU Cache Key, Value, Node.Value Real World Interpretation

Tags: caching, data-structures, linked-list, hashmap, lru

I understand how in principle an LRU cache works. For example, see here: https://java2blog.com/lru-cache-implementation-java/

However, I am having great difficulty understanding how this is interpreted in a real world setting. For example, if I want to store objects (which have no natural numbering/order), I understand that the value (in the hashmap) is just a pointer to a node in the linked list, but what does the key represent?

Furthermore, what does the node.value represent? I think this the actual object which is being cached. However, how does this correspond to the key in the hashmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical hashmap has a key and a value, both of arbitrary type. The key is the thing you want to index the structure by, and the value is the thing you want to store and retrieve. Consider a normal hashmap in Java:

```
Map<UUID, Person> peopleById = new HashMap<>();
```

You can pass in a UUID to a `.get` method and get the person associated with that UUID, if it exists.

The LRU caches used in the real world are like that as well:

```
Map<UUID, Person> cachedPeopleById = new LRUCache<>(10);
```

The UUID is the key, and the Person is the value.

The reference implementation you linked to doesn't use generics, it only supports `int` to `int`, which is the equivalent of `Map<Integer, Integer>`. The `Node` class in the reference implementation isn't something that ought to be exposed in public methods. So in that reference implementation, `Node` should be hidden, and `delete(Node)` and `setHead(Node)` should be private, because otherwise they expose implementation details of the cache.

A better implementation would be something more like this (doing this off the top of my head, might have compilation errors, for illustrative purposes only):

```
public class LRUCache <KeyType, ValueType> implements Map<KeyType, ValueType> {

    private static class Node <KeyType, ValueType> {
      KeyType key;
      ValueType value;
      Node prev;
      Node next;

      public Node(KeyType key, ValueType value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
      }
    }

    int capacity;
    HashMap<KeyType, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    Node head=null;
    Node end=null;

    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
      this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public ValueType get(KeyType key) {
      ...
    }

    public set(KeyType key, ValueType value) {
      ...
    }

    private void delete(Node<KeyType, ValueType> node) {
      ...
    }

    private void setHead(Node<KeyType, ValueType> node) {
      ...
    }
```